# WARNING : createConnector contains empty path annotation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Using documentation of confluent for kafka_cluster

I got this error :

```
Jul 03, 2018 4:20:41 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
```

I used docker-compose

Comment: This is a warning, not an error.... What exactly isn't working? What step in the documentation are you at?